# How to fix slow load time when calling wmi(processor only)

Tags: c#, wmi

I am encountering a problem with my C# application.

I am using WMI to retrieve some information about my CPU, GPU and RAM.
All works well and fast except the CPU (`Win32_Processor`).
I have a menu and different panels for each (CPU, RAM, GPU).
At first what I tried was to load all the info with the start of the application, didn't work quite, took so much time to load.
Second, I tried loading them when the panel was visible (after clicking the button) and that worked quite well on ram and gpu panels.
I used the same exactly code for all of them. Here it is:
I am trying to make the cpu information load as fast as the others if possible but from searching and trying my own things I cannot make it happen.
I do realise that it takes some time in order to take all the info, just seems weird that it needs that much time!
P.S: Load time when you click the button for the cpu panel is 3.5 seconds and when you click the "specs" button just to show maxfreq, number of cores, data width, thread count, current voltage as well as l2, l3 size takes 8 seconds.

```
private void getinfo(string hwclass, string syntax, string name)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hwclass);
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
    {
        string valuebro = Convert.ToString(mo[syntax]);
        if (name == "CPUNAME")
        {
            CPUNAME.Text = valuebro;
        }
        else if (name == "CPUMAXFREQ")
        {
            //CPUMAXFREQ.Text = "Clocked at " + valuebro + "Mhz";
            maxfreqbro = Convert.ToInt32(valuebro);
        }
        else if (name == "CPUCURFREQ")
        {
            curfreqbro = Convert.ToInt32(valuebro);
            CPUMAXFREQ.Text = "Frequency: " + valuebro + "Mhz";
        }
        else if (name == "ThreadC")
        {
            THREADC.Text ="Threads: " + valuebro;
        }
        else if (name == "DataW")
        {
            DataW.Text = "Data Width: " +valuebro + " bit";
        }
        else if (name == "L2Size")
        {
            l2size = Convert.ToInt32(valuebro) / 1000;
            L2Size.Text = "L2 Size:  " + l2size.ToString() + " MB";
        }
        else if (name == "L3Size")
        {
            l3size = Convert.ToInt32(valuebro) / 1000;
            L3Size.Text ="L3 Size:  "+ l3size.ToString() + " MB";
        }
        else if (name == "NOC")
        {
            NoOfCores.Text = "Cores: " + valuebro;
        }
        else if (name == "VOLT")
        {
            voltage = Convert.ToDecimal(valuebro) / 10;
            output = voltage.ToString();
            CurrentVolt.Text = "Core Voltage: " + output + " V";
        }
        else if (name == "CPUSTATUS")
        {
            CPUSTATUS.Text = "Status: " + valuebro;
        }
        else if (name == "AVAIL")
        {
            Avail.Text = "Code: " + valuebro;
        }
    }
}
```

(RAM)

```
private void raminfo(string hwclass, string syntax, string name)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher ram = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hwclass);
    foreach (ManagementObject rm in ram.Get())
    {
        string valueram = Convert.ToString(rm[syntax]);
        if (name == "OED")
        {
            OEDRAM.Text = "" + valueram;
        }
        else if (name == "ERRINFO")
        {
            ErrInfoRam.Text = "Error code: " + valueram;
        }
        else if (name == "ERRDESC")
        {
            ErrDescRAM.Text = "" + valueram;
        }
        else if (name == "CCVOLT")
        {
            volts = Convert.ToDecimal(valueram) / 1000;
            finaloutput = volts.ToString();
            voltageram.Text = "Voltage: " +finaloutput + " V";
        }
        else if (name == "CCSPEED")
        {
            Currentspeed.Text = "Current Frequency: " + valueram + " Mhz";
        }
        else if (name == "SPEED")
        {
            speedram.Text = "Max Frequency: " + valueram + " Mhz";
        }
        else if (name == "CAPA")
        {
            Int64 capa = Convert.ToInt64(valueram) / 1024;
            Int64 final = capa / 1024;
            capacityram.Text = "Total memory: " + final + " MB";
        }
    }
}
```

(GPU)

```
private void gpuinfo(string hwclass, string syntax, string name)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher gpu = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hwclass);
    foreach (ManagementObject gp in gpu.Get())
    {
        string valuegpu = Convert.ToString(gp[syntax]);
        if (name == "GPUNAME")
        {
            NameGPU.Text = valuegpu;
        }
        else if (name == "Availability")
        {
            AvailGPU.Text = "Status code: " + valuegpu;
        }
        else if (name == "CONFMEC")
        {
            CMEC.Text = "Error code: " + valuegpu;
        }
        else if (name == "DVer")
        {
            DriverVers.Text = "Driver Version: " + valuegpu;
        }
        else if (name == "ERDESC")
        {
            ErrDescr.Text = valuegpu;
        }
        else if (name == "ERRCLR")
        {
            ErrorClear.Text = valuegpu;
        }
        else if (name == "STAT")
        {
            StatusGPU.Text = "Status: " + valuegpu;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is terribly inefficient to call `getinfo` over and over again, making full WMI queries for all the values, and then just using one of them. It seems useless to pass in `hwclass` when the method is hardcoded to `Win32_Processor` values. It seems unnecessarily confusing to create a new name for each data element that is only used in an `if` that could test the WMI data element name as easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple change filtering the WMI Query to the field being requested sped up my queries over 100 times:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", $"SELECT {syntax} FROM " + hwclass);
```

However, it still makes multiple queries for no reason. A more efficient version that queries all the needed fields in one go could be written and is 3 times faster still. This version includes other suggested improvements:

```
private void cpuinfos(List<string> dataElements) {
    ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", $"SELECT {String.Join(",", dataElements)} FROM Win32_Processor");
    foreach (ManagementObject cpuInfo in mos.Get()) {
        foreach (var anElementName in dataElements) {
            string valuebro = Convert.ToString(cpuInfo[anElementName]);
            switch (anElementName) {
                case "Name":
                    CPUNAME.Text = valuebro;
                    break;
                case "MaxClockSpeed":
                    //CPUMAXFREQ.Text = "Clocked at " + valuebro + "Mhz";
                    maxfreqbro = Convert.ToInt32(valuebro);
                    break;
                case "CurrentClockSpeed":
                    curfreqbro = Convert.ToInt32(valuebro);
                    CPUMAXFREQ.Text = "Frequency: " + valuebro + "Mhz";
                    break;
                case "ThreadCount":
                    THREADC.Text = "Threads: " + valuebro;
                    break;
                case "DataWidth":
                    DataW.Text = "Data Width: " + valuebro + " bit";
                    break;
                case "L2CacheSize":
                    l2size = Convert.ToInt32(valuebro) / 1000;
                    L2Size.Text = "L2 Size:  " + l2size.ToString() + " MB";
                    break;
                case "L3CacheSize":
                    l3size = Convert.ToInt32(valuebro) / 1000;
                    L3Size.Text = "L3 Size:  " + l3size.ToString() + " MB";
                    break;
                case "NumberOfCores":
                    NoOfCores.Text = "Cores: " + valuebro;
                    break;
                case "CurrentVoltage":
                    voltage = Convert.ToDecimal(valuebro) / 10.0m;
                    output = voltage.ToString();
                    CurrentVolt.Text = "Core Voltage: " + output + " V";
                    break;
                case "Status":
                    CPUSTATUS.Text = "Status: " + valuebro;
                    break;
                case "Availability":
                    Avail.Text = "Code: " + valuebro;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You use it by passing the values you want to collect:

```
cpuinfos(new List<string>() { "Name", "MaxClockSpeed", "ThreadCount" });
```

Comment: Hello sir , thank you for the fast response ,I am novice and I have couple of questions if its not that much of a trouble. My first question is where valuebro.Dump(anElementName); (Whats the assembly reference of the string.Dump and my Second question is , I cant seem to understand what the method takes as input. Sorry again if those are stupid questions.

Comment: @G.Peos Not at all - my fault. The `Dump` call is debugging left over from testing in LINQPad (a great product). I added a sample call.

Comment: Thank you so much , sir.